# Pyspark joining 2 dataframes on 2 columns optionally

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using the below code to join 2 dataframes together. I want to join `df1.col1` with `df2.col2` firstly if possible. If it does not find a match then it should join `df1.col1` with `df2.col3`. Is the first argument always the first join priority?

```
df = df1.join(df2, (df1.col1 == df2.col2) | (df1.col1 == df2.col3), "left")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code will work perfectly fine.

```
df = df1.join(df2, (df1.col1 == df2.col2) | (df1.col1 == df2.col3), "left")
```

As your left join will match `df1.col1` with `df2.col2` in the result if the match is found corresponding rows of both df will be joined. But if not matched, then `df1.col1` will try to find a match with `df2.col3` and all the results will be in that `df` as output.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the first argument always the first join priority?

No, there is no first or second argument in the join condition, it is a single boolean expression.

If there is a row that matches the first condition and a row that matches the second condition, both rows will be joined. For example this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .getOrCreate()

data1 = [
    ("1",),
]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ["col1"])

data2 = [
    ( "1", "a", "val1",),
    ( "2", "1", "val2",),
    ( "3", "c", "val3",),
]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ["col2", "col3", "value"])

df1.join(df2, (df1.col1 == df2.col2) | (df1.col1 == df2.col3), "left")\
.show()
```

Will produce the following output:

```
+----+----+----+-----+
|col1|col2|col3|value|
+----+----+----+-----+
|   1|   1|   a| val1|
|   1|   2|   1| val2|
+----+----+----+-----+
```

If you have a preferred match, you will have to filter out the extra matches. In general you will probably need to aggregate the rows and check what/how many matches each row of the first dataframe got in the second, but the exact implementation depends on your business logic